# Using Ionic with latest PushKit for iOS 13, Has anyone recently accomplished this?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, voip, pushkit

I currently have a VOIP app using Ionic 4, WebRTC, Socket.IO with a very lightweight node.js backend. It is working really well, and is currently using normal push notifications for calls. Which has its limitations.

My issue is that I want to mature the push notifications to fit more properly with the standard VOIP native look and feel. More specifically I need the ability to receive phone calls using the native call interface so I can get features like ringtones, ending/accepting calls, and answering with bluetooth devices. So on iOS this is pushkit, and on android not 100% sure what this is. I have looked at the following libraries and so far each has had there issues. My main concern is most of them are not compatible with the newest version of iOS 13, which has some VOIP changes in it.

https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/CordovaCall

https://github.com/Hitman666/cordova-ios-voip-push

https://github.com/Taracque/cordova-plugin-voippush

Really my big question is this, has anyone successfully built a project using Ionic 4 and the latest version of iOS/Android that captures the look and feel of a native phone call using push notifications?

Links to examples would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: Hey @Bobisback, did you manage to this working? I tried this plugin https://github.com/mattkhaw/cordova-plugin-callkit - but it is not working when app is killed in Cordova

Comment: I mean that link is the magic sauce that got all this to work. The full discussion is linked here: https://github.com/Hitman666/cordova-ios-voip-push/issues/16. Basically what it boils down to is you need to merge the two plugins together, which he did in the above link you had. Based on my understanding it was not plug and play. 

I have not specifically done this but there are a couple of people in that discussion that claim to have gotten it to work correctly.